# vectorize stringr str_match to remove a for loop

Tags: r, stringr

how can I use R vectorization to remove this for loop?

```
library(stringr)
url <- c("http://www.slate.fr/france/87869/mehdi-nemmouche-bruxelles", "http://www.slate.fr/story/87347/turquie-opposition-geek", "http://www.slate.fr/grand-format/paysages-debarquement-photos-1944-aujourdhui")

for (i in 1:length(url)) {
a[i]<-str_match(url[i], "http://.*slate.fr/(.*?)/")[2]
}
```

This does not work:

```
a<-str_match(url, "http://.*slate.fr/(.*?)/")[2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `[,2]` instead of `[2]` because the output is a 2 column `matrix` and by indexing `[2]`, you are getting only the 2nd element i.e. `"http://www.slate.fr/story/"` instead of the `2nd` column`.

```
str_match(url, "http://.*slate.fr/(.*?)/")[,2]
#[1] "france"       "story"        "grand-format"
```

From the description of `?str_match`

> Vectorised over ‘string’.  ‘pattern’ should be a single pattern,
>        i.e. a character vector of length one.